# Can VPN or TOR protect me from my ISP

Tags: security, vpn, web, privacy, tor

For connecting to internet I need to open the ISPs website and login. I believe during this my IP address can be tracked. So how will VPN or TOR help here. If not any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your literal question:
**Your ISP** can **always** track your IP. They are the once who gave that IP to you. (Neither TOR or a VPN will help with this).

However if you are worried about them tracking webpages which you visit then you can log in on your ISP's portal and start either your VPN or TOR afterward. They will still know your IP, but not the IPs of the hosts which you visit.

(In non computer terms you asked something like: My phone provider gave me a mobile and a phone number. How can I prevent them from knowing what my phone number is).

Comment: So they know my IP but still can't see my activities because it's encrypted?

Comment: Correct. (text to make comment 15 chars long)

Comment: Great, so only thing left is remote desktop. If I ensure that he cannot see my screen by remote desktop I will have full privacy.

Comment: Remote desktop is disabled by default. And even if you enable it someone will need to know your computer password. (which is hopefully not the same password as your used for your ISPs captive portal).

Answer (score 1):

> So how will VPN or TOR help here.

You need to be connected to the internet to use both of these solutions.  This involves doing the process you describe.

> If not any other solution?

What are you trying to avoid exactly because the process you describe cannot be avoided.

Comment: So if my ISP decided to mess with me, there is nothing which I could do?

Comment: @user1677158, since your ISP provides the pipe, there's not much you can do.

Comment: @user1677158 - What do you mean "mess with me" exactly?  An ISP can only view the data in and the data out.  It will be unable to connect and access your computer.